# Dapper and implicit conversion of strings to custom types

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a class called AdviceId which supports implicit conversion to/from strings. I have also overridden the ToString() method on the class to ensure that the correct string output is returned whenever this method is called.

My application persists data using Dapper. Previously AdviceIds were persisted and retrieved as strings, but I've now tried to use the specific type instead. However, this fails. Is there a special trick to tell Dapper to use implicit conversion between a string and my AdviceId type?

**UPDATE**
I have managed to get Dapper to insert an instance of AdviceId as a string by adding a type map to the SqlMapper

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(AdviceId), DbType.String);
```

and by making AdviceId implement IConvertible. However, I've had no luck converting a string, from the db, back to an instance of AdviceId.

Comment: Does `AdviceId` have a public constructor?

Comment: This isn't implemented *today*, but in theory it could work... would need code adding in a few places, though. Because dapper works at the meta - programming level, it won't spot implicit conversions without being explicitly told to.

Comment: @Oded - AdviceId actually didn't have a public constructor. I have changed this now, however, as there wasn't a very good reason why I should hide the constructor.

Comment: @Marc - Are the changes significant? I can pull the source for Dapper rather than use the NuGet package and make the required changes myself if, perhaps, you're able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Øyvind that depends on how familiar you are with IL-emit. Basically, it would be somewhere in the guts of `GetTypeDeserializer` or `CreateParamInfoGenerator`

Comment: @Marc - I will give this a stab. I have done very little work with IL-emit, and it's been years since I last touched it. But it's a nice challenge!

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Marc added [in June 2014](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/e26ee0abe5bdff561ff59fded87cabb9f5d983a1) and you can call `AddTypeHandler` with your own implementation of `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<AdviceId>` which I found via [this blog](https://andydote.co.uk/2014/07/22/configuring-dapper-to-work-with-custom-types/) but Marc also blogged [here](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/07/dapper-gets-type-handlers-and-learns.html).

```
public class AdviceIdTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<AdviceId>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, AdviceId value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.ToString();
    }

    public override AdviceId Parse(object value)
    {
        return new AdviceId((string)value);
    }
}

SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new AdviceIdTypeHandler());
```