# Cannot insert Boolean into Oracle using Dapper

Tags: oracle, dapper

I'm having trouble inserting a boolean into an Oracle 12 database using Dapper.

The exception I get is
`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BOOLEAN`

The CommandText is

```
INSERT INTO crossqueryb.counterparty (Id,Name,IsBroker,DefaultPortfolioId) VALUES (:Id,:Name,:IsBroker,:DefaultPortfolioId)
```

`IsBroker` is defined as a `NUMBER(1)`.

When I inspect the OracleParameter the DbType and OracleDbType properties are set to `Boolean`. The value is `false`, the type of the value is `object {bool}`.

The parameters are passed to the Query method as an `IDictionary<string,object>`, not as the actual domain type or an anonymous type.

Do I need to write a custom typehandler for this or am I missing something else obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL [does not have a `BOOLEAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012) data type ([PL/SQL does](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348) but not SQL).

> `IsBroker` is defined as a `NUMBER(1)`.

You will need to convert your boolean value to a numeric value as Oracle will not know how you intend to perform the conversion (`false/true` => `0/1` or `-1/+1` or `-7/3`).

Comment: Yeah I sort of expected Dapper to do that for me, are you saying it does not and I need to write my own TypeHandler?

Comment: @John I have not used Dapper so can only tell you what is happening from Oracle's side. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23502237/1509264) and [this documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dapper/6/type-handlers/11/converting-varchar-to-ihtmlstring) would suggest, yes, a type handler is the answer.

Comment: @John: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365865/pass-c-sharp-bool-as-parameter-to-oracle-using-dapper, the TypeHandler only applies to queries, not parameters. You can try the solution from that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about .NET Core using Dapper to connect to Oracle DB.
I use this with procedure and it works.
Nuget install Dapper.Oracle.

Example:

In your C# model:

```
public bool someBoolValue { get; set; }
```

In your C# repository:

```
using Dapper;
using Dapper.Oracle;

//in your method
var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("SOMESQLVARIABLE", yourModel.someBoolValue, OracleMappingType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameters.Add("OUT_REFCURSOR", dbType: OracleMappingType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
var result = await _dbConnection.ExecuteAsync("my_proc",
                                              parameters,
                                              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return result;
```

DB procedure:

```
PROCEDURE my_proc(
    SOMESQLVARIABLE IN    NUMBER,
    out_refcursor   OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
)AS
BEGIN
    OPEN out_refcursor FOR SELECT
                               some_column
                           FROM
                               my_table
                           WHERE 
                               my_col = SOMESQLVARIABLE; -- my_col is NUMBER(1,0)

END my_proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple Oracle function if you want to avoid the Dapper type converter:

```
create or replace function bool_to_num(value boolean) return number is
begin
    if (value is null) then
        return null;
    elsif (value) then
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    end if;
end;
```